# Spark - Drag values from previous day

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to update daily `itemPrice` values for a column `dailyRecords` in a DataFrame. Below is the schema of that particular column.

```
|-- dailyRecords: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dayId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- itemPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- itemsPurchased: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- itemSku: string (nullable = true)
```

(please note there can be many other columns). We can assume dayId can be a sequence being incremented from 1 to 365.

So for each `itemSku` when the `itemsPurchased is greater than 0` and `itemPrice is equal to 0` then update `itemPrice` from the `previous dayId` (eg: if `dayId is 10` if this condition satisfies get `itemPrice from dayId 9`), else leave the `itemPrice` as it is and move on to the next `dayId`

Any leads to the desired solution or possible approaches will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

**After math considering the comments another alternate solution when multiple columns to be updated more efficiently :**

The schema for above `dailyRecords` is obtained by combining multiple columns from `another dataframe` . So considering the comments it is better to update the `itemPrice` when it is in a separate dataframe rather than doing it after nesting the columns together in one column `dailyRecords`.

So here's my solution to update `itemPrice` values using `foldLeft`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62307771/12322995

Please note in this solution I'm using `foldLeft` is because I have more columns to be updated than just the `itemPrice` outside the question.

Comment: Can you show the schema of input data before doing the `collect_set` on `dailyRecords`.

Comment: @ParvezPatel I have just edited the question by removing collect_set thought it. might be confusing. 
So the column `dailyRecords` is nothing but all columns in a different dataframe which are mapped to one single column using this - `struct(AnotherDF.columns.map(col): _*).as("dailyRecords")`  then a `collect_set ` is done on `dailyRecords` which will finally have the schema I have mentioned baove

Comment: My point was, instead of doing the price update after doing all this `struct` and `collect_set`, it would be done with using `Window` function on the `anotherDF`. Added my answer below. Kindly check and accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `dragPricesFromPreviousDay` takes two parameters, one is the list of columns to be updated and another is that dataframe it needs to perform the update on.

Notice I did `.na.fill(0, Seq(priceCol))` in the function is because if there is no previous day value for the column it adds `null` when the condition is met. So we can get rid of nulls by filling them with a literal 0 or any other value.

```
def dragPricesFromPreviousDay (PricesNeedsUpdateDF: DataFrame, AllColumnsToBeUpdated: List[String]): DataFrame ={

    import spark.implicits._
    val windowFunc = Window.partitionBy("itemSku").orderBy("dayId")

    val dragPricesFromPreviousDayDF = AllColumnsToBeUpdated.foldLeft(scoresNeedsUpdateDF) {
      (df, priceCol) =>
        df.withColumn(priceCol,
          when($"itemsPurchased".gt(0) && $"itemPrice".equalTo(0), lag($"$priceCol",1).over(windowFunc))
            .otherwise($"$priceCol"))
          .na.fill(0, Seq(priceCol))
    }
    dragPricesFromPreviousDayDF
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to generate the correct itemPrice in anotherDF itself before doing the `struct` and `collect_list` as shown below:

```
scala> val anotherDF = List(
     | (1,10.11,5,"item1"),(2,15.45,3,"item1"),(3,0.0,3,"item1"),(4,17.50,4,"item1"),
     | (1,10.11,5,"item2"),(2,0.0,0,"item2"),(3,16.50,3,"item2"),(4,17.50,4,"item2"),
     | (1,20.20,5,"item3"),(2,0.0,3,"item3"),(3,30.50,3,"item3"),(4,0.0,4,"item3"),(5,0.0,4,"item3")
     | ).toDF("dayId","itemPrice","itemsPurchased","itemSku")
anotherDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dayId: int, itemPrice: double ... 2 more fields]

scala> anotherDF.show
+-----+---------+--------------+-------+
|dayId|itemPrice|itemsPurchased|itemSku|
+-----+---------+--------------+-------+
|    1|    10.11|             5|  item1|
|    2|    15.45|             3|  item1|
|    3|      0.0|             3|  item1|
|    4|     17.5|             4|  item1|
|    1|    10.11|             5|  item2|
|    2|      0.0|             0|  item2|
|    3|     16.5|             3|  item2|
|    4|     17.5|             4|  item2|
|    1|     20.2|             5|  item3|
|    2|      0.0|             3|  item3|
|    3|     30.5|             3|  item3|
|    4|      0.0|             4|  item3|
|    5|      0.0|             4|  item3|
+-----+---------+--------------+-------+


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> val ww = Window.partitionBy("itemSku").orderBy("dayId")
ww: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@4cb9f248

scala> anotherDF.withColumn("updatedPrice", when(col("itemPrice")===0 && col("itemsPurchased")>0, lag("itemPrice",1).over(ww)).otherwise(col("itemPrice"))).show
+-----+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
|dayId|itemPrice|itemsPurchased|itemSku|updatedPrice|
+-----+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
|    1|     20.2|             5|  item3|        20.2|
|    2|      0.0|             3|  item3|        20.2|
|    3|     30.5|             3|  item3|        30.5|
|    4|      0.0|             4|  item3|        30.5|
|    5|      0.0|             4|  item3|         0.0|
|    1|    10.11|             5|  item2|       10.11|
|    2|      0.0|             0|  item2|         0.0|
|    3|     16.5|             3|  item2|        16.5|
|    4|     17.5|             4|  item2|        17.5|
|    1|    10.11|             5|  item1|       10.11|
|    2|    15.45|             3|  item1|       15.45|
|    3|      0.0|             3|  item1|       15.45|
|    4|     17.5|             4|  item1|        17.5|
+-----+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
```

Then use the `updatedPrice` from `anotherDF` as your `itemPrice`.

Comment: That was actually a good idea as it is less complicated. I have implemented the same but by using foldLeft as I have multiple columns to be updated in that dataFrame. Thanks!